# Add Checkbox to database in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

Im not 100% great in html and databases but I'm getting there. What I did works but not when I'm editing a page that has checkboxes.

**In my database migration:**

```
$table->string('check_this')->nullable();
```

**In views:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    @if ($job->check_this == 'selected')
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_this" value="selected" checked>Yes.</label>
    @else
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_this" value="selected">Yes.</label>
   @endif
</div>
```

Once the checkbox is checked, it writes to the db so my if statement wont work correctly. Is there a way that if unchecked it deletes the value from the database?

Maybe I have go about this is the wrong way as in the correct format for checkboxes in a migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration should looks like this:

`$table->boolean('check_this');`

and the view part:

`@if ($job->check_this)`

See: http://laravel.com/docs/master/schema#adding-columns for all avail types of 'columns' in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox don't send nothing if is not cheched so the database will not update unless you check in controller and if "check_this" is not set in your request set this to 0 on database.

```
$obj = Obj::find($id); //get your object from database 
$input = Request::all(); //or $request->all() if you use requests
if(!isset($input['check_this'])){
 $input['check_this'] = 0; //or whatever you want
}
$obj->fill($input);
$obj->save();
```

Note:
You can simplify your view

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_this" value="selected" @if ($job->check_this == 'selected') checked @endif>Yes.</label>
</div>
```

And of course the answer about using boolean for this field will optimize your database if you don't need this specific string.